# Django: formset errors without li / *

Tags: django, django-templates, formset

I am using a formset. `formset.non_form_errors` are displayed exactly the way I need it. However my field specific errors in `for dict in formset.errors` are always displayed inlcuding the `<li>` tag. I tried `.as_text`, however that just added a * (and removed the li). But I don't need the * either.

Anyone who can help me with that?

```
{% if formset.total_error_count %}
    {% if formset.non_form_errors %}
        {% for error in formset.non_form_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                {{ error|escape }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for dict in formset.errors %}
        {% for error in dict.values %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                {{ error|escape }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be fixed by moving the individual errors in the form loop:

```
{% if formset.total_error_count %}
    {% if formset.non_form_errors %}
        {% for error in formset.non_form_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                {{ error|escape }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% for form in formset %}

    {% if form.quantity.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            {% for error in form.quantity.errors %}
                {{ error|escape }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```